# Logging missing variables in FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

Does anyone know how to list the variables that are missing from the data model of a FreeMarker template? I am trying to give some nice information to the user, such as:

"template defines field "foo" but no data was provided"

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out which variables are missing would be to evaluate the template, since the template language itself is a programming language.

You could try executing the template from within java, catching exceptions, stubbing out those variables and repeating that process until you have them all.